# Free resolution by $A$-bimodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

In [these notes](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Ekassel/Kassel-ICTPnotes2004.pdf) on (co)homology of algebras, Kassel claims (page 14) that the Hochschild standard resolution of a $k$-algebra $A$, with group of $q$-chains equals $$C'_q(A):= A \otimes A^{\otimes q} \otimes A$$  is a resolution of $A$ by free $A$-bimodules.

**Question.** Why is $C'_q(A)$ free as $A$-bimodule? In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338953/resolutions-of-bimodules-as-re-modules) Mariano Suárez-Álvarez explains that if $A$ is projective as $k$-module, then $C'_q(A)$ is projective as $A$-bimodule, but the claim in Kassel's notes stronger (he does not take any assumption on $A$).

Comment: Is $k$ a field? And are these tensor products over $k$?

Comment: $k$ a field is the case I mainly care, so yes we can assume that. Tensor products are considered over $k$.

Comment: I would regard $A\otimes_k A$ is a free bimodule of rank one; would you agree?

Comment: I absolutely agree. But what about a higher $q$-fold tensor product of copies of $A$?

Comment: OK, then $A\otimes A^{\otimes q}\otimes A\cong(A\otimes A)^m$ as $A$-bimodules for a suitable $m$.

Comment: I see, so this strongly depends on $k$ being a field. If $k$ is a commutative ring, then I guess this is false in general and one have to impose conditions on $A$ to get some projectiveness condition on $q$-chains, just as Mariano explains, right?

Comment: Mariano Suarez-Alvarez said that if $A$ is projective as $k$-module, then $C'_q(A)$ is a projective $A$-bimodule. In this sentence, you can replace "projective" by "free". So if $k$ is a field, this is indeed automatic, otherwise you just need the freeness of $A$ as a $k$-module. The proof is straightforward : if $A\simeq k^n$, then $A\otimes A^{\otimes q}\otimes A=A\otimes (k^n)^{\otimes q}\otimes A=A\otimes k^{n^q}\otimes A=(A\otimes A)^{n^q}$.